# Looking for a simple example of Transition Semantics

Tags: formal-languages, semantics

I want to define a semantics of a DSL through transition semantics. For my DSL I defined the syntax and implemented a code generator. Although I can provide a demo by giving examples, I want to write the semantics of my DSL to provide a formal specification of it.

However I don't know how to do it!. Can someone provide me with an example?

Comment: I migrated this from cstheory, as I feel that it is more appropriate here. It is not research level. Apologies for not commenting on the original post.

Comment: @DaveClarke Essentially I'm asking how to turn a set of transformation rules into semantical definitions. Anyway hope I get an answer here!

Comment: If you have an existing set of transformation rules, perhaps you could write some of them in your question, to give the answerer something specific to work with.

Comment: I agree. Without (part of) the syntax definition and and idea what your informal semantics look like, you won't get a specific answer.

Comment: This question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/formally-describing-a-new-domain-specific-programming-language asks more or less the same thing. If you want any more specific information, you will need to ask a more specific question with examples etc.

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "transitional semantics"? If you mean structural operational semantics using transition systems, then maybe a good place to start is a good text on the semantics of programming languages, Examples:

- Winskel's [Formal Semantics of Programming Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262731037).
- Hennessy's [Semantics of Programming Languages](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/Matthew.Hennessy/slexternal/resources/sembookWiley.pdf).
- Nielson & Nielson's [Semantics with Applications](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~bra8130/Wiley_book/wiley.html).

I recommend ignoring denotational semantics for your task.

Since the semantics of programming languages is really well-understood, most of the work in formalising DSLs usually comes from the domain-specific part of the language.